# CSS Sourcemap works in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: css, less, source-maps

On a big legacy project based on JSF 2, I'm trying to set some less stylesheets with [less4j](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j).

My test page is loading a simple `import.min.css` stylesheet, compiled and compressed by less.

Everything is working fine, except the sourcemap on Chrome.

---

When looking in the DevTools Sources tab, I can see the compiled css with the sourcemap at the end:

[image: main css file with sourceMappingURL at the end]

Using `chrome://net-internals/#events`, I can check that Chrome is calling the sourcemap `.map` url.

In the same tab, I can see the imported `.less` files are well retrieved from the source map, and I can browse them without any problem:

[image: list of less files retrieved from css sourcemap]

[image: content of a less file, retrieved by the sourcemap]

So, it seems the sourcemap is well read and well understood by Chrome.

But in the DevTools Elements tab, when checking a DOM element, Chrome only shows the compiled CSS reference:

[image: Chrome DevTools Elements tab, not working]

On the contrary, Firefox handles the sourcemap perfectly:

[image: Firefox Elements tab, working]

The sourcemap content is probably right, as Firefox handles it and Chrome parses it fine in its Source tab. So, what did I do wrong?